# Visualising the cumulative hierarchy

Tags: recursion

I would like to visualise von Neumann's cumulative hierarchy of sets as in the following picture from Wikipedia: [image]

How can I define a recursive procedure which gives me V_n for every natural number n?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It would be helpful if you provided an actual link, or explained a bit how each figure is generated from the prior figure (i.e., explain the recursion).

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tedious at the moment...not recursive (because i do not yet understand the recursion taking place).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\neumann[1]{\begingroup\fboxsep=1pt\def\?##1{\fbox{##1}}%
  \vcenter{#1}\endgroup}
\begin{document}
$V_0\neumann{\?{}}$

$V_1 \neumann{\?{\?{}}}$

$V_2 \neumann{\?{\?{}\,\?{\?{}}}}$

$V_3 \neumann{\?{\?{}\,\?{\?{}}\,\?{\?{\?{}}}\,\?{\?{}\,\?{\?{}}}}}$

$V_4 \neumann{} \ldots$
\end{document}
```

[image]